# Sonar running tests from a different solution (.NET)

Tags: .net, testing, selenium, sonarqube, gallio

So here is my scenario, I have .NET project, lets call it FooBar, which is a web application, and in a entirely separate solution I have a .NET project lets call it FooBarSeleniumUITests to test the web application using Selenium Webdriver, it is intended to be a black box integration test suite. Now what is the best way to get this test suite reported into sonar as part of the FooBar report, and, if possible have a list of test from the test suite be kicked off at build time and need to pass for the build to be successful. I already have the test suite loaded into gallio icarus, however the sonar gallio plugin page states that the integration tests must be in the analysed solution, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Running your ITs prior to launching the Sonar analysis and using "sonar.gallio.it.mode=reuseReport" (along with "sonar.gallio.it.reports.path" and "sonar.gallio.it.coverage.reports.path" to find the XML reports) should make it.

See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/sonar-dotnet-gallio-plugin

However, you must make sure that you do not move your sources to another folder, otherwise the test/coverage reports will contain wrong paths and Sonar won't be able to attach those test/coverage results to your project resources.